# The type Type[Array] is not generic and not indexable

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

This program:

```py
class Array:
    def __init__(self, underlying):
        self.underlying = underlying

    def __class_getitem__(cls, key):
        return Array(key)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Array({self.underlying=})"

def foo(name, kind):
    pass

foo(name="x", kind=Array["int"])
```

is flagged by `mypy`:

```
x.py:17: error: The type "Type[Array]" is not generic and not indexable  [misc]
```

The `__getitem__` is something I added just to see if it would resolve the issue (it did not). I'm not intending to use `Array` here as a type (in the `typing` sense), just for cute syntax to pass an array type somewhere else.

What does this `mypy` error mean and how can I fix it (preferably with something other than `# ignore` comments)?

Comment: Classes cannot be indexed.  Class INSTANCES can be indexed.  The `__getitem__` you wrote would apply if you created an instance of `Array`.  Compare to the built-in `array` module.

Comment: @TimRoberts [Yes they can](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/#class-getitem).

Comment: Not saying what you're doing shouldn't work, but how is the "cute syntax"  `Array["int"]` "cuter" than the identical `Array("int")` here? I wouldn't be surprised if you have an older version of `mypy` that doesn't recognize `__class_getitem__` returning non-strings yet, and/or that `mypy` is opinionated and doesn't think non-`Generic` classes should be indexed, even when it's technically possible.

Comment: Side-note: For subclassing correctness, the body of `__class_getitem__` should be `return cls(key)`, not `return Array(key)`

Comment: What do you mean by "array type" if not "in the `typing` sense"? I was thinking, depending on what it's used for, maybe you could make it align with "the `typing` sense", and I'd be happy to add that to my answer.

Comment: @wjandrea It ends up being used to generate some C++ code (not for any Python type-checking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not intending to use `Array` here as a type (in the `typing` sense), just for cute syntax to pass an array type somewhere else.

`__class_getitem__` is only for typing. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__):

> *classmethod* `object.__class_getitem__(cls, key)`
>
> Return an object representing the specialization of a generic class by type arguments found in *key*.

And [more specifically](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-purpose-of-class-getitem):

> Using `__class_getitem__()` on any class for purposes other than type hinting is discouraged.

So unfortunately, it looks like what you want is not possible. Just use the regular constructor syntax, `Array("int")`.

---

Also, just in case you weren't aware, special methods [shouldn't be used in unintended ways](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers):

> *Any* use of `__*__` names, in any context, that does not follow explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.

Comment: P.S. I'm not a typing expert, so LMK if I got any details wrong.

Comment: That's very annoying. Seems like a really bizarre limitation if true, since you can easily achieve the same thing by just having a global object. Plus the [PEP itself](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/#class-getitem) has an example of this which very much is not used as a type.

Comment: @Barry Sorry, what do you mean about using a global object?

Comment: @Barry Regarding the PEP, it doesn't seem to mesh with Mypy, yeah, but I *think* some hypothetical type checker could consider a string like `"MyList[int]"` as a deferred type hint.

Comment: Could make a type `Array` decorated with `@type.__call__` with a `__getitem__`, so now I have an object named `Array` with an index operator. Except `mypy` doesn't like that _either_... so I could make a type `ArrayCreator` with a `__getitem__` that returns an instance of `ArrayType` or something, and create an object `Array` of type `ArrayCreator`. Which works and mypy is fine with it, but it's a lot of extra... uh... typing to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `__class_getitem__` is reserved for typing generics. What *isn't* reserved, and is still available, is the metaclass's `__getitem__`, which allows you to provide the same API.

With this, your example can be made to pass type checkers by introducing a fake metaclass with a `__getitem__` on it ([mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=1bed22f10bd0fa5c4b61a4ad9b371727), [Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?pyrightVersion=1.1.337&code=GYJw9gtgBA%2BjwFcAuCQFM5QJYQA5hCSgEMA7UsJYpLMUgZwChGd9CokBPXLUgcxhoAHkjQNaDEvQ7MswDgDoAKgE0ACgFEYAYQASG7QGkAkgDkA4gC5GUW1ADGAG2L1pMAIIgQxTgFk0VAAUXLhoAJTWdlFQACZo8nB8AViiEHCB9GiOwAA0UADWaJyWUPRIIHkA9GFQALQAfFCe3sVQCu2MWZmRdh5ePv5UUAC8HNxozIxOLtLNPoEQAcTTrsN9LYPEETZ2cQkwvCnpmdl5CKRxII6cvHzb0XYnwArnl9e3I1CvaFc3-MxRPawGBlEDHLLAe4PKDoFAgUhQYAAIjmnECAG8ni8Lj93vxhgBfMJIgG7eLAlb0GBJGipdJOeh5QqcGoNJr9Yo7B6w1AI1GBZlhZhA4BgMCBUjERZM3gxKG2XAzZjoABuaGIjhgITQgVRAG0kbwkEiALpC0XiyWLYZIoRImUXYb6w2kY1moA))

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing_extensions as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:    
    class _ArrayMeta(type):
        def __getitem__(self, key: str, /) -> Array: ...
else:
    _ArrayMeta = type


class Array(metaclass=_ArrayMeta):
    # The rest of the code remains identical
    def __init__(self, underlying):
        self.underlying = underlying

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Array({self.underlying=})"

    def __class_getitem__(cls, key) -> Array:
        return Array(key)

def foo(name, kind):
    pass
```

```
>>> foo(name="x", kind=Array["int"])  # OK
>>> reveal_type(Array["int"])  # `Array`
```